# Рафтинг, дайвинг, каякинг, тимбилдинг и прочие — а есть ли альтернатива?

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы, заимствования

В современном русском языке появилось огромное количество *-инговых* заимствований. Но если посмотреть с практической точки зрения:

- тенденция к сокращению слов в речи и на письме существует уже почти как век (винтовка, камералка, неучтёнка и т.д.)
- слова на *-инг* представляют вполне годные краткие замены длинным описаниям типа: сплав на рафтах, ныряние с аквалангом, сплав на каяках, работа по укреплению  отношений в команде и т.д.

И встаёт два вопроса:

- существует ли в русском языке адекватная замена заимствованному суффиксу *-инг-*?
- если в языке есть потребность в кратком выражении тех или иных понятий и процессов, но нет адекватных словообразовательных инструментов, то так ли плохо заимствование?

Answer (score 3):

Термины с суффиксом ИНГ **сложно заменить русскими суффиксами по ряду причин**:

1) они обычно описывают **сложный процесс**, а не образуются от одного глагола;

2) в них используется **иноязычная основа**, плохо сочетающаяся с русскими суффиксами и семантически, и фонетически.

3) В качестве мотивирующего слова используются **не только глаголы**.

4) иногда термин **заимствуется полностью** (тимбилдинг), а не образуется н русской почве.

5) **Суффиксов для образования отглагольных существительных у нас немного**, да и те имеют стилистическую окраску:

**НИ/ ЕНИ/ АНИ** (книжн.): бетонирование,  анкетирование,  сложение, согласование, управление;

**К:**  кладка, шпаклевка; гравирование – гравировка, маркирование – маркировка, прессование – прессовка, шлифование – шлифовка;

**Нулевой суффикс:** вылет, жим, обжиг, промер, сброс, нагрев – нагревание, обжиг – обжигание.

**Для справок**

**Рафтинг** — (англ. raft плот): Рафтинг спортивный или туристический сплав по водотокам.

**Да́йвинг** (англ. «diving» от англ. «to dive» — нырять) — это подводное плавание со специальным снаряжением.

**Каякинг** – это сплав по бурной реке на одноместном судне, который и называется каяком.

**Командообразование, или тимбилдинг** (англ. Team building — построение команды) — термин, обычно используемый в  бизнесе для создания и повышения эффективности работы команды. Это  различные мероприятия для сотрудников организации для укрепления командного духа, так как дружеские, теплые отношения между сотрудниками  улучшают качество работы,

Answer (score 1):

1. В данном случае английский суффикс выполняет функцию образования отглагольного существительного (в ваших примерах существительные образованы от прилагательного или причастия). В русском нашлись бы суффиксы и окончания такого назначения, но их зачастую неестественно использовать в сочетании с корнем слова, заимствуемого как краткий термин.
2. В ваших примерах оправдание заимствований состоит в сокращении количества слов при передаче смыслов, существующих и в русском (сплав на надувных плотах, подводное плавание, поход за покупками - шопинг и пр.). Не всегда бывает удачным употребление заимствованных одиночных слов взамен изначально русских или устоявшихся на основе более раннего заимствования. Например, исполнителя заказного убийства стали называть киллером, хотя исходное английское слово столь конкретного оттенка не имеет (наёмный убийца - hitman). Троеборье без видимых причин стали называть триатлоном, всех спортсменов - атлетами (так в английском их отличают от охотников); соглашения и договорённости отныне понадобилось "имплементировать"  и т. п.